# Composition of different functions from prelude

Tags: haskell

i wrote a function `h ys =(map (+4)(filter(<5)ys))`
can anyone explain to me why this can be rewritten as.

```
h  = map (+4) . (filter (<5))

(filter (<5)) :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
(+4) :: Num a => a -> a
```

how can we compose these two with a dot then return type of filter is not same as the argument of `(+4)`?

Comment: because, by definition, `(f . g) x = f (g x)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're composing `map (+4)`, not `(+4)`, which has a type of `Num a => [a] -> [a]`, which works with `filter (<5)`'s type of `(Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: Like this (map (+4)).(filter(<5)) ?
when i run  (map (+4)).(filter(<5)) [1,2,3] I get error

Comment: Exactly. Function application binds more tightly than operators do.

Comment: if i have this def h  = map (f . (+4)) . (filter (<5))
will it be same as
h1=map f (map (4+) (filter(<5) ys)) ?

Comment: do you know what map(:) does?
i can't even test it.

Comment: you should call it like `(map (+4)).(filter (<5)) $ [1,2,3]` or `map (+4) $ filter (<5) [1,2,3]` which are both exactly the same as `map (+4) ( filter (<5) [1,2,3] )`.

Comment: @user2975699 `Prelude> :t  map(:)` -->
`map(:) :: [a] -> [[a] -> [a]]` ; 
`Prelude> :t map (:) [1,2,3]` -->
`map (:) [1,2,3] :: (Num a) => [[a] -> [a]]` ; 
`Prelude> :t map (:) "123"` -->
`map (:) "123" :: [[Char] -> [Char]]`